# ScrollView over scrolls with .paging

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a paged vertical scroller and am seeing a weird problem where the ScrollView "over scrolls" to the next page. The frames appear to be correctly sized (based off border debugging) and I disabled my TabBar which I thought might've been the problem. Here are screenshots of the first, second, and twentieth slide and code:

[image: page1]
[[image: page2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBORdl.png)
[image: page3]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(colors[i % colors.count].opacity(0.6))
                            .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
                        Text("Video \(i + 1)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .bold()
                    }
//                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
```

Adding `.ignoreSafeArea` around the ScrollView stops the paging problem but now the ZStack will go into the TabView.

```
TabView {
  ScrollView(.vertical) {
      LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
          ZStack {
            Rectangle()
              .fill(colors[i % colors.count].opacity(0.6))
            Text("Video \(i + 1)")
              .font(.title)
              .bold()
          }
          .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
          .containerRelativeFrame([.horizontal, .vertical])
        }
      }
      .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

**Edit:**
Apparently it's a bug with SwiftUI. There are a few different options in the meantime that can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77636423/20386264)

Comment: I tried attaching `.containerRelativeFrame` to a few different places. No dice, unfortunately

Comment: This post might help: [iOS 17 SwiftUI: Color Views in ScrollView Using containerRelativeFrame Overlap When Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77636423/20386264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right except `ZStack frame`. Vertical pagination on the other hand, has generated worries about `safeArea` both the top and the bottom. As a result, each page frame will have safeArea limitations at the top and bottom. To make it work, you may try making each page frame fill up to screenHeight:

```swift
TabView {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(colors[i % colors.count].opacity(0.6))
                        Text("Video \(i + 1)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .frame(height: geo.size.height + geo.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    //Or LazyVStack spacing
                    .padding(.bottom, geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top, .bottom])
    }
}
```

**Updated:** Adjust the content view with TabView by wrapping it up inside a `GeometryReader` to set ZStack frame manually equal to (screenHeight - TabView height). Then add a padding to the bottom equal to safeArea bottom constraint. This means each page height is equal to the screen height except safeArea bottom and the entire content padding to the safeArea bottom constraint.

[image]

Comment: Hmm so that works-ish. No more of the cutoff but the ScrollView now ignores a TabView wrapped around it

Comment: What TabView? Can you edit the question? I'm assuming it's a kind of one page view which has scrollView inside.

Comment: question is edited

Comment: I updated the answer, you may want to take a look. @Jack

Comment: Thank you! I went with one of BennyNeez's answers but really appreciate the help. Going to mark this as answered