# How to fix incorrect scroll indicator inset in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a view similar to the one below:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Text("something here")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .background(Color.red)
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { row in
                        HStack {
                            Text("row \(row)")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that vertical scroll indicator showed on the List starts from incorrect position as on the screenshot below. It looks like some additional padding is added on top. Is there any way to fix in in SwiftUI? I checked that some kind of workaround like below with UIKit works but it is far from being a proper solution. Is there any better way to do this? I'm looking for a solution that works on iOS 15 if that makes any difference.

```
.onAppear(perform: {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
        let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first
        let views = window?.recursiveSubviews()
        let scrollViews = views?.filter({ $0 is UIScrollView }) as? [UIScrollView]
        scrollViews?.forEach({ $0.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets = .init(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) })
    })
})

[...]

extension UIView {
    func recursiveSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        return subviews + subviews.flatMap({ $0.recursiveSubviews() })
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be another issue relating to the *bottom* safe area insets (see below for links to other posts). It doesn't happen on devices where the bottom insets are 0, such as an iPhone SE.

My guess is that the scroll indicators are designed to stay out of the safe area insets. So the height of the vertical indicator is (height of list) - (height of insets). The resulting height is then being (erroneously) vertically centered on the list, which means there is a gap of half the bottom inset above the scroll indicator.

If the `List` stays out of the inset at the bottom then there is no gap. This will be the case if a tiny amount of bottom padding is used to break the contact with the bottom inset. A `GeometryReader` can be used to measure the safe area insets, so that padding is only applied when necessary:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    List {
        // ...
    }
    .listStyle(.plain)
    .padding(.bottom, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 ? 1 : 0)
}
```

However, when you do this, then of course the `List` doesn't scroll through the bottom inset. So it's not a great workaround.

I tried various tricks involving negative padding and offsets but, unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to have the `List` fill the bottom inset without the problem being seen.

Other not-great workarounds would be:

- don't use a `List`
- hide the scroll indicator by applying `.scrollIndicators(.hidden)`
- use `.insetGrouped` as `ListStyle`: the `List` then has some padding at the top which makes the gap to the scroll indicator less noticeable.

---

Here are some other posts with issues that are only seen when the device has bottom safe area insets:

[iOS 17 SwiftUI: Color Views in ScrollView Using containerRelativeFrame Overlap When Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77636423/20386264)
[TabView content stops off-center after an animated transition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78165247/20386264)
[SwiftUI TabView insets are not respected during rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77785372/20386264)