How to show & hide a view when scrolling in SwiftUI?
I'm trying to implement functionality that shows/hides a header view when the content beneath is scrolled. Starting with the header showing, what I'd like to have is when the ScrollView is scrolled up, the header should scroll up & out of view with it. When the ScrollView is scrolled down by some delta say header view height, I'd like for the header to come into view again. I have the following code trying to do so (not accounting the header height as of now) by identifying the scroll direction but the header view appearance is erratic when scrolling up or down.
import SwiftUI

struct NewContentView: View {
    private let gridItemSpacing: CGFloat = 2
    private let gridColumns = 5
    @State private var showingHeader = true
    @State private var lastScrollPosition: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = .none

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if showingHeader {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .transition(
                        .asymmetric(
                            insertion: .push(from: .top),
                            removal: .push(from: .bottom)
                        )
                    )
            }
            GeometryReader { outer in
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    gridView(outer)
                        .background(GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.frame(in: .named("ScrollView")).minY)
                        })
                }
                .coordinateSpace(name: "ScrollView")
                .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                    guard let value = value else { return }
                    let delta = lastScrollPosition - value

                    if abs(delta) > 1 {
                        scrollDirection = delta > 0 ? .up : .down
                        if scrollDirection == .up && showingHeader {
                            withAnimation {
                                showingHeader = false
                            }
                        } else if scrollDirection == .down && !showingHeader {
                            withAnimation {
                                showingHeader = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    lastScrollPosition = value
                }
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
    }
    
    private func gridView(_ geo: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: gridItemSpacing),
                                 count: gridColumns), spacing: gridItemSpacing) {
            ForEach(0..<300) { index in
                let itemSize = (geo.size.width - CGFloat(gridColumns - 1) * gridItemSpacing) / CGFloat(gridColumns)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum ScrollDirection {
    case up, down, none
}

struct ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewContentView()
}

Any help is appreciated. Intended behaviour can be seen as implemented in another answer here.

Would I be right in thinking that the only difference to the post you referenced is that you want the header to move with the content when it is being scrolled out of view, instead of moving independently and quite quickly?

That's correct, the experience I'm looking for is exactly the same as the referenced post. On scrolling upwards, the header should move with the content. And when scrolling downwards if the amount scrolled is equal to or greater than the height of the header then the header should scroll back into view.

@BenzyNeez fwiw, I tried your solution from the referenced post but it had issues working with LazyVGrid so I tried to go about with a different approach.

Background (can be skipped)
I was asking in a comment, whether you want the header to move with the scrolled content as the content is scrolled up. I tried a few ways of doing this, but it's difficult to get the header to move in-sync with the scrolled content at times, but independent of the scrolled content at other times. An overlay approach came closest (apply the header as an overlay to the ScrollView using top alignment, hide by setting negative y-offset) but then the header covers the scroll indicator when the indicator is at the top, so this is not great either.
The solution provided in the answer to the other post works slightly differently. The header is removed with a push transition as soon as scroll-up is detected and restored when scroll-down is detected. The answer has an edit which shows how to adapt the solution so that the header is only hidden or shown after the scroll view has been scrolled a threshold distance. It was my answer by the way.
I tried that solution with the LazyVGrid from your example and found it actually works OK if the header is only hidden after scrolling a threshold distance. However, there were some errors in the console reporting action tried to update multiple times per frame. This may be due to the lazy container changing size.
Anyway, you said you wanted the same behavior as in the other post, by which I understand, you don't want to have to scroll up by a significant amount before the header is removed.
Something that works
Here is another approach, which is altogether simpler:

Instead of using a GeometryReader to measure the scroll offset, it uses .scrollPosition to track the id of the grid item that is top-leading.

The modifier .scrollTargetLayout is applied to the LazyVGrid. An .id needs be applied to each of the grid items. The ids shoulds be sequential.

The header is removed as soon as the content is scrolled up by half the height of one grid row. This is still not quite what you said you were looking for, but the threshold is now much smaller than with the other approach.

The header is restored as soon as the content is scrolled down by more than one grid row.

The turning point is still tracked, but it now represents the id where scrolling had previously reached.

By tracking the turning point, it allows the re-show to depend on a scroll movement of more than one row.

To prevent the header from showing too early if the scroll view bounces at the bottom, apply a max. ceiling to the turning point. I've used a hard-coded value of 250 below, but ideally it should be calculated from the number of rows, height of a row and height of the screen.


This approach does not generate errors in the console, so I think it's better.
struct NewContentView: View {
    private let gridItemSpacing: CGFloat = 2
    private let gridColumns = 5
    @State private var showingHeader = true
    @State private var turningPoint = 0
    @State private var scrolledId: Int?

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outer in
            let safeAreaInsets = outer.safeAreaInsets
            VStack(spacing: gridItemSpacing) {
                if showingHeader {
                    headerView
                        .transition(
                            .asymmetric(
                                insertion: .push(from: .top),
                                removal: .push(from: .bottom)
                            )
                        )
                }
                ScrollView(.vertical) {
                    gridView(screenWidth: outer.size.width)
                }
                .scrollPosition(id: $scrolledId, anchor: .topLeading)
                .background {
                    Color.clear
                        .onChange(of: scrolledId) { oldVal, newVal in
                            if let newVal, let oldVal {
                                if (showingHeader && newVal < oldVal) || (!showingHeader && newVal > oldVal) {
                                    turningPoint = min(newVal, 250) // bounce protection
                                }
                                if (showingHeader && newVal > turningPoint) ||
                                    (!showingHeader && turningPoint - newVal > gridColumns) {
                                    showingHeader = newVal < turningPoint
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
                // Fix for gap to scroll indicator, see
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/78220604/20386264
                .padding(.trailing, safeAreaInsets.bottom > 0 && safeAreaInsets.trailing == 0 ? 1 : 0 )
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: showingHeader)
    }

    private var headerView: some View {
        Text("Header")
            .font(.title2)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .frame(height: 80, alignment: .top)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.red)
    }

    private func gridView(screenWidth: CGFloat) -> some View {
        let itemSize = (screenWidth - CGFloat(gridColumns - 1) * gridItemSpacing) / CGFloat(gridColumns)
        return LazyVGrid(
            columns: Array(
                repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: gridItemSpacing),
                count: gridColumns
            ),
            spacing: gridItemSpacing
        ) {
            ForEach(0..<300) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
                    .id(index)
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
}



Thanks for giving it a go. Yeah I was hoping to have the same behaviour as in the other post. I'm AFK at the moment so I'll give this a try as soon as I can.

Answer updated to track the scroll position by id instead of using a GeometryReader. I think it's a better approach. Hopefully it's closer to what you are aiming for.

Thanks man, this worked fine. Appreciate your help!
