SwiftUI carousel that supports paging (snap to view on scroll)
I am trying to create a custom carousel view using SwiftUI and my desired result is to:

Create a carousel view that supports continuous scrolling and paging
It should be compatible with iOS 15 and 16 so I cannot use scrollTargetBehavior(_:) and scrollTargetLayout(isEnabled:)

The end result I want is something like this video:
The top carousel shows the snapping and paging behavior and the below carousel shows the continuous scroll.
This is the code I have so far which gives me the continuous scroll for all versions but only the the snapping behavior for iOS 17+
import SwiftUI

struct CarouselView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    
    
    private var showsIndicators: Bool
    private var spacing: CGFloat
    private var offset: CGFloat
    private var shouldSnap: Bool
    
    init(showsIndicators: Bool = true,
         spacing: CGFloat = 0,
         offset: CGFloat = 0,
         shouldSnap: Bool = false,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.offset = offset
        self.shouldSnap = shouldSnap
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: spacing) {
                content
                    .offset(x: offset)
            }
            .apply {
                $0.apply {
                    if #available(iOS 17.0, *), shouldSnap {
                        $0.scrollTargetLayout()
                    } else {
                        $0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .apply {
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *), shouldSnap {
                $0.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            } else {
                $0
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func apply<V: View>(@ViewBuilder _ block: (Self) -> V) -> V { block(self) }
}

How can I support the paging behavior for versions under iOS 17 ?
I have seen some implementations with TabView and while initially it did show some promise in that it supported snapping / paging, the limitations for me are:

It only shows 1 view at a time, I need to be able to show the next element
I want to be able to customize the spacing between the current element and the next

Can I achieve this without needing to dive into UIKit and CollectionView ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77639021/833395 If it can help. this answer.
